# Scheduled post delete - can't pass the cron arguments

Tags: functions, wp-cron

Thanks to everyone who takes a look. I've spent countless hours trying to make this work, but no matter what I tried it still doesn't work. Hopefully I'm missing something simple, but I'm stuck...

Here's my code on the submit page where I add a new page and a cron job to delete it in the future:

```
$seconds = time() + $_POST["days"] * 86400;
wp_schedule_single_event($seconds, 'crondelete', $new_post_id );
```

And here's the relevant code in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'crondelete', 'delete_page_in');
function delete_page_in($args) {
wp_delete_post($args);
}
```

The cron part is working properly:
[image]

But it looks like the parameter isn't passed to the function, so once I run the cron job- nothing happens(the page won't delete).

Comment: The third parameter should be an array of arguments - check [this example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_single_event/#comment-1042).

Comment: Thank you Sally, I've checked the answer from below first, but it's essentially the same issue as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing your code to the Wordpress function [**wp_schedule_single_event**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_single_event#Parameters), it appears you failed to indicate that parameters would be passed.

Perhaps the following version of your code will work for you.

```
add_action( 'crondelete', 'delete_page_in',10,1);
wp_schedule_single_event($seconds, 'crondelete', array($new_post_id ));
```

Notice the [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) now includes two extra parameters:  10=Priority, and 1=Accepted Arguments to be passed.

Comment: Thank you Mike, it worked :) PS I've already tried those parameters before, but as far as I understand the accepted arguments aren't needed in this case, since it's 1 by default. I think the array part is what I was missing.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. For others' sake ... WHile the additional parameters (10,1) are not required in this instance, I always include them for readability and consistency with other code blocks. That makes it easier for junior developers to spot patterns in my code blocks.